# Cookie is not getting set in HTTP request in JAXWS when it's set using context

Tags: cookies, jax-ws

I am trying to set cookie from client using below code snippet, I am using JAXWS RI 2.2.3.

```
Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) portType).getRequestContext();
Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
httpHeaders.put("Content-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
httpHeaders.put("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(cookie));
ctxt.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
```

From the SOAP log I see that Cookie is not getting set, but it's set in the context header.
Any other header is getting set except Cookie and I am not able to find out the reason.
I need to get a session from one service and set it to another service to work with it, but I am not able to do so here.

HTTP headers: {Cookie=[mysession="529fc605-8188-7f3b-21ad-92407976d5a9";], Accept-Encoding=[gzip], Content-Encoding=[gzip]}

---[HTTP request - https://10.112.83.155:443/eam/sdk/]--- Accept: text/xml, multipart/related Accept-Encoding: gzip Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 [] Set-Cookie: vmware_soap_session="529fc605-8188-7f3b-21ad-92407976d5a9"; SOAPAction: "urn:internaleam/2.0" User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.3-b01-

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in JAX-WS. Bug link: [JAX_WS-1044](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1044)

Currently fixed in JAX-WS 2.2.7 which is not yet released.